# android gps time of fix ( gettime() ) method

Tags: android, time, gps, location

According to Android documentation, using the .getTime() method in the Android location will return the UTC time of this fix, in milliseconds since January 1, 1970. How can I set it to a datetime format such as 2012-03-13 19:15:27.550 so that i will know the specific date and time of the fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Date class has a constructor that can take a long value:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29)

From there, you can query the date, or format it however you like.